# Groovy - FindAll - unique record - condition declared by field

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, mapping, unique

I have a json as below

```
    {
    "Animals": [
        {
            "Name": "monkey",
            "Age": 4
        },
        {
            "Name": "lion",
            "Age": 3
        },
        {
            "Name": "lion",
            "Age": 3,
            "Misc": "001"
        }
    ]
}
```

2 elements out of 3 inside json array has the Name and Age. The only difference is that 3rd element has Misc and the 2nd does not have Misc.

**How to get the record having Misc when there are 2 records with same Name and Age?**

Below is what I tried

```
parsedJson?.Animals = parsedJson?.Animals?.unique().findAll{animal -> animal?.Misc?.trim() ? animal?.Misc?.trim() : site?.Name?.trim() };
```

Looks like I missed one more statement or I missed something inside unique()
I also tried

```
parsedJson?.Animals = parsedJson?.Animals?.unique{a1,a2 -> a1?.Misc <=> a2?.Misc}
```

but still not get what I want

What I want is

```
{
    "Animals": [
        {
            "Name": "monkey",
            "Age": 4
        },
        {
            "Name": "lion",
            "Age": 3,
            "Misc": "001"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is by grouping the elements and then just merge
the maps.

`groupBy` is used to group the elements by their "primary key" -- lets
assume, that this is `Name` and `Age`.  The resulting data structure is
a map with `[it.Name, it.Age]` tuples and keys and a list of elements,
that hold that property.

Next reduce over the list of maps and just merge them.  This assumes,
that the information there does not contradict itself (e.g. only adds to
the result).  Otherwise the last map would just win.

```
def data = [["Name": "monkey", "Age": 4], 
            ["Name": "lion", "Age": 3], 
            ["Name": "lion", "Age": 3, "Misc": "001"]]

println data.groupBy{[it.Name, it.Age]}.collect{ _, xs -> xs.inject{ acc, x -> acc.putAll x; acc } }
// → [[Name:monkey, Age:4], [Name:lion, Age:3, Misc:001]]
```